# logstash grok plugin to parse log files

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a dataset like this:-

```
1. Sun Jul  5 00:04:01 EDT 2015

2. root         1     0  0.0  0.0   640  10372 Apr20 init [3]         
3. root         2     1  0.0  0.0     0      0 Apr20 [migration/0]
```

And I need to filter out the timestamp from first line and add it with each message from second line.

Please help me to do this using `logstash grok plugin`.

Comment: Unfortunately, logstash typically treats each line as a distinct event.  I've not seen a way to do what you're asking.

Comment: I agree with @AlainCollins, Logstash processes each line independently and doesn't keep a memory of previous lines.

Comment: There's a poorly documented metaevent filter plugin that _I suspect_ provides this functionality.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metaevent.html